# Significance of combined lagged and contemporaneous variables

Tags: regression

In several analyes I performed, I occasionally observed that when dealing with lagged variables, including contemporaneous values of the same variables in the regression increases the signficance of the lagged variables. The contemporaneous values are insignificant themselves nevertheless.

For example, I regress market returns on the lagged value of a variable, i.e. X(t=-1). The coefficient is significant and also robust to other controllvariables. Nevertheless, when I include the value X(t=0), the coefficient gains substantial significance, e.g. p jumps from 2.4% to 0.1%. The coefficient on X(t=0) is insignificant though, but adj. R² increases.

I am not sure what to make out of this. Should I include X(t=0) as long as there is economic intuition to it?

Best
Micha

Comment: What are the explanatory variables? It sounds like you're dealing with endogeneity issues.

Comment: the explanatory variable mentioned is a sentiment index I built. It is supposed to forecast the movements.

Comment: The sentiment index probably has your lagged returns in it. Take a look at [this write up](http://www.business.otago.ac.nz/econ/seminars/Abstracts/2013/Reed20Sept_Doc1.pdf) on endogeneity

Comment: thanks a lot. unfortunately I have to give in my thesis at sunday, so i will probably not go deeper into the topic. will read the article though, much appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming it's BSc or MSc thesis. In this case, try to get a parsimonious model, fewer variables is better, so long their signs are correct.

Comment: Thanks Aksakal, your comments are much appreciated. Indeed this what I thought of. I stick with the parsimonious model but refer to the observed results when including X(0) and put the results in the appendix.

Comment: Aksakal, could you describe how I could test for endogeneity? As I understand potentially by using lagged values of the dependent variable?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy test for this. I would try and avoid this topic given the deadline.

Comment: A simple test would be to regress $y_{t}$ only onto $y_{t-1}$ without a constant in the model. If there's a significant $|\beta_{y_{t-1}}| \approx 1$, that tells you right off that your dependent variable is integrated/non-stationary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Alexis. So it has something to do with non-stationarity? I already use first differences and the dfuller test does not imply non-stationarity of the first difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to make a statement about the specifics of your data and model, but you might have a read of de Boef and Keele (2008): they motivate compare and relate different kinds of auto-distributed lag and generalized error correction models to one another.

In at least some forms of error correction model, we disaggregate short run effects into instantaneous change and lagged effects. Perhaps your model specification without current levels collapsed two different short run relationships into a single measure (e.g. something along the lines of merging an instantaneous and lagged effects, when in reality only lagged effects are present)?

**References**

De Boef, S. and Keele, L. (2008). Taking time seriously. *American Journal of Political Science*, 52(1):184–200.